# Making inner div scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I enable scroll on inner `DIV`, when body is set to `overflow:hidden` as I have limitation editing body `CSS`

Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/sgh1gqh5/)

Body CSS is

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Inner DIV css is following - and by default the height of the div is being set by jQuery.

```
.custom-gallery-lineage {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: try to give it fixed height

Comment: Why set the height with js, why not just use css to set it - otherwise you will need to remember to reset it if the window is resized

Comment: Using only CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/sgh1gqh5/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$(document).height()` you have to use `$(window).height()`, Check below snippet or updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sgh1gqh5/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var winw = $(window).width();
 var winh = $(window).height();
 $(".custom-gallery-lineage").height(winh);
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #000;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
.custom-gallery-lineage {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-gallery-lineage">
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am just wondering why I did not tried before..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you're setting the `height` of the element to match the `document`. Instead, use the `window`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var winw = $(window).width();
  var winh = $(window).height();
  $(".custom-gallery-lineage").height(winh);
});
```

Better still, don't use JS at all, and set the height using `vh` units in CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.custom-gallery-lineage {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-gallery-lineage">
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
  <p>This is test content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var winw = $(document).width();
 var winh = $(window).height();
 $(".custom-gallery-lineage").height(winh);
});
```